# Projection Matrix between two Vectors

Tags: geometry, matrices, projective-geometry

Given a two normal vectors `v1 = [a1;b1;c1]` and `v2 = [a2;b2;c2]` as given in  [Fig1.](https://people.fh-landshut.de/%7Emaurer/fembat/img157.png) How I can derive the projection matrix that project vector `v2` into vector `v1`.

I computed the cross product and the angle `(θ)` between them using the dot product, But I'm little bit confused which is the correct way to derive the projection matrix.

Update: Both vectors have the same origin in 3D space `(0,0,0)`.

Comment: This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Orthogonal_projection) will help. Basically, if $u$ is the unit column vector you are trying to project onto, the matrix is $uu^T$.

Comment: The projection of $v_2$ onto $v_1$ is given by $\dfrac{\langle v_2,v_1\rangle}{\|v_1\|^2}$.  Easy.  Now plug in the coordinate vectors to achieve the desired matrix.

Comment: Of course the projection is $\dfrac{\langle v_2,v_1\rangle}{\|v_1\|^2}v_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider first the case where $v_1$ has unit length. Then $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$ is the length of the projected $v_2$. It goes in direction $v_1$, so the vector corresponding to that length is $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle v_1$. Now consider a vector which is a multiple of this unit length $v_1$, namely $\lambda v_1$. This factor $\lambda$ will scale the result by $\lambda^2$, one factor of $\lambda$ for each kind of multiplication. Which tells you that you have to divide by the square of the norm of $v_1$ in those cases where $v_1$ is not of unit length:

$$\frac{\langle v_1,v_2\rangle}{\langle v_1,v_1\rangle}v_1$$

Now you can turn this into a matrix by noting $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=v_1^Tv_2$. Then you can write

$$\frac{\langle v_1,v_2\rangle}{\langle v_1,v_1\rangle}v_1=
\left(\frac{1}{\lVert v_1\rVert^2}v_1v_1^T\right)v_2$$

so you have the matrix

$$M = \frac{1}{\lVert v_1\rVert^2}v_1v_1^T$$